# How to use the \foreach parameter as a bend angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, foreach

Take a look at the following MWE (rather ME, since it actually does not work):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
  \tikz \graph [nodes={empty nodes, fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, draw}]{
      \foreach \i in {-10,0,10}
      a --[bend left=\i] b;
    };
\end{document}
```

The `\i` that is used for `bend left` causes a bunch of errors; changing it into a fixed value like `10` works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works: add braces around the loop code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
  \tikz \graph [nodes={empty nodes, fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, draw}]{
      \foreach \i in {-10,0,10} { a --[bend left=\i] b; }
    };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For curiosity: why do we need braces here? The example in 14.14 of the PGF manual also has braces, but other examples do not (e.g. the second loop on the front page). What is the difference?

Comment: @Jeroen The manual says that if a brace doesn't follow the list of items, everything up to the first `;` is used as `<commands>`. In those examples, however, there's always something like `\draw` or `\fill` at the start. Perhaps it's this that causes the confusion. Anyhow, adding braces is safer, in my opinion.

Comment: O, now I found the explanation for `\foreach` in section 83. Thanks!